# Какая структура для очереди с приоритетом?

Tags: очередь, c++

Для обычной очереди:

```
struct ochered {
    int info;
    ochered  *prev, *next;   //указатель на предыдущий и след эл-ты
}
```

Comment: в функции которая добавляет делаем цикл на сравнение приоритета...

обычно это `priority_cur ">" priority_next` и идём далее при true...

хранить приоритет можно хоть в самой ячейке хоть в объекте...


но лучше воспользоваться уже готовым :) 

в std::priority_queue приоритет сравнивается через предикат

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, а функцию добавоения можно?

Comment: @dimchik мне за тебя её написать?

ну это очень просто! подумай! весь алгоритм я уже расписал!

посиди покури мануалы вроде этого [тык][1]  или [этого][2]  (первый лучше)

помни девиз программистов "только программируя, ты научишься программировать" 


  [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/priority_queue/
  [2]: http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

Comment: В одном из планировщиков Linux используется RB-tree.

Comment: @avp  а причём тут цветные деревья? ТС спрашивал о приоритетной очереди...

Comment: По сути там это именно очередь к CPU с приоритетами (в качестве приоритета выступает текущий (рассчитываемый на данный момент) диспетчерский приоритет потока, готового к выполнению).

Поток с наибольшим приоритетом выбирается первым. Для равных приоритетов первым будет тот, который попал в очередь раньше.

А балансированное двоичное дерево - это удобный контейнер.

Comment: @avp ну вот а я про что? ... зачем ТС бинарные деревья ? он  на данный момент не понимает как вставить что то в середину списка (очереди). а тут ещё и RB-tree ему предлагают :) 

по-моему раз он не разобрался в `priority_queue` то ему рано ещё RB-tree...

p.s. спасибо за инфу о RB-tree (я не знал о таком)

Comment: > ochered

Это прекрасно, ящитаю.

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, деревья ему для общего развития. Может ТС задумался, что поддержание списка в отсортированном виде процедура достаточно дорогая, вот и спрашивает, а как еще можно поступить?

Вообще-то, если множество допустимых значений приоритета сильно ограничено (скажем, десятки), то проще всего использовать вектор обычных очередей, упорядоченный по приоритету.

Тогда проблема вставки в середину списка отпадает.

Comment: > struct **ochered**

> а функцию **добавоения**

Напомнило
![...][1]
[1]: http://cs5908.userapi.com/v5908654/892/jmkjxkP7Vhw.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Классически, очередь с приоритетами реализуется на базе структуры данных "Двоичная куча" (Binary heap).

Не хочется тут повторять информацию, которой полно в интернете. Поэтому вот несколько ссылок:

- [ru.wikipedia.org/Двоичная_куча](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0)
- [ru.wikipedia.org/Очередь_с_приоритетом](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)
- [Пост на хабре про двоичную кучу](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112222/)